# Pods cms and "advanced custom fields" plugin

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, cms, pods-framework

We are planning to build a quite big database to store data for our 5000 yearly subscribers association.

We were considering pods cms for our needs since it permits a good flexibility in building a complex website and is performance aware while managing the database.

But recently I red on the pods cms website that they're having some funding problems, so they're struggling reaching the 2.0 milestone.

We're afraid that the development could stop.

On the other side we found "advanced custom fields" that also seems a good alternative. Furthermore it has a stronger business model.

So what would you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Development of Pods 2.0 definitely won't stop, the funding problems explained in that dev post were alluding to an upcoming announcement that we'll be pushing some of the enterprise and "extra" functionality of Pods 2.0 into a premium version targeted towards firms with more advanced and specific needs.

On the data structure, Pods 2.0 handles post types, taxonomies, and more. It even will have a migration feature to move between different content types. You probably won't be worse off by going with ACF right now, and eventually having to migrate to Pods, as you'll have a solution that works well for you when you need it (now).

Even if you don't use Pods, good luck with your project and I'm sure people would love to see the site you're working on when it's done if you find time to follow up with how it all worked out for you.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I didn't mean to be rude :) As you know the choosing of frameworks is one of the first and hardest steps in the development process, and i have to try my best to foresee the best for my no-profit association (also because i won't be there forever and cannot know whether my successor will be programming savvy as me).

Said that i already chose to give a try to pods and already posted a question on the Q&A page of your site that approach more specifically what I need to achieve.

Comment: No worries, I hope I didn't seem to think you were being rude, that wasn't the case :) I totally know you've got to make decisions, glad you gave Pods a try in the end!

Comment: Oh and I just replied to the Q&A question you posted, hope it helps you.

Comment: ehm yes, i'm a pretty picky person :)
I'll give you the "answered" since is the most complete answer!

Comment: and because i appreciate a lot developers that give support to their products in places like stackoverflow!

Answer (score 6):

ACF is a great plugin that makes WordPress feel more like a 'real' CMS.  It lets you turn attach any data type to any post type (built-in or custom), has conditionals for where those data fields will show up, and is ridiculously easy to add to your theme.  More to the point, if multiple end users are going to be adding content, WordPress with ACF is better than anything else I've run into.

I'm wondering what your user database has to do with it, though.  Are these going to be WP users, or just live in the same database?  Will you be showing this data somewhere on the site?

Also, love the OP reference.